# how to generate listview with data from sqlite and also from online sources

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to create a app which shows news in a list view. And i am planning to cache the news offline in sqlite and show it to the user. but oly certain amount of news will be cached... say 10... But when the user presses load more button in the bottom of listview i should get the news feed list from online and append it to the existing listview.

how to achieve this? I will be using Cursor to load the offline data but the remaining online news will be coming in a form of list... And i cant add this to sqlite db cuz user will set in preferences that oly 10 news to cache...

Comment: you can use cursor to load the rest of the data as well

create a new object that extends from cursor, and in its methods load the data from the server

Comment: use a MergeCursor, it can concatenate several Cursors into one,  eg SqliteCursor and MatrixCursor

Comment: Oh that sounds cool... can you guide me with some reference links?

Comment: @pskink : I sud use sqlite cursor to get data from db and use matrix cursor to get data from online and merge these two cursors using merge cursor and show it to the user and i sud just get the data from online source when user presses the load more button and add it to matrix cursor.... Am i rite?

Comment: @pskink : thank you... i will try that....  thanks once again..